# Disconnecting a totally disconnected set with a ball.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Suppose that $K$ is a compact subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$ that is totally disconnected (meaning that for any two distinct points
$x, y\in K$, there are disjoint open subsets $U,V\subseteq {\mathbb R}^2$, such that $x\in  U$, $y\in  V$ and $K\subseteq U\cup V$).

Does there necessarily
exist $x_0\in {\mathbb R}^2$, and $r>0$, such that $K$ intersects both the interior and the exterior of the ball $B(x_0,r)$, but not
its boundary?

You are welcome to replace the metric in ${\mathbb R}^2$ by one that is equivalent to the usual metric, and hence
change the shape of a ball to something else, such as a regular polygon.

Comment: I'm not sure if $C \times C$ where $C$ is the cantor set in $[0,1]$ is a counter-example. If not, then maybe $C \times C$ where $C$ is a "fat Cantor set" would be a counter-example? I'm not sure of this, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: @AdamRubinson. The ball centered at $(0,0)$  with radius a bit bigger than the diagonal of a square with length 1/3 works for the usual Cantor set.

Comment: @Adam.  Replacing the metric with $d(x,y)=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$, the ball centered at $(0,0)$ and radius 1/2 does it for the fat Cantor set as well.

Comment: Yes, there are planar discontinua (totally disconnected compact subsets) which cannot be separated by any convex curve. The construction is similar to that of the Antoine discontinuum in $R^3$, which cannot be separated by any 2-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are planar discontinuums (subsets homeomorphic to the Cantor set) which cannot be separated by any closed convex curve. Below is a sketch of a construction that follows the same idea as the one of the  [Antoine's necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine%27s_necklace). The latter is a discontinuum in the 3-space $E^3$ which cannot be separated by any topological 2-dimensional sphere in $E^3$.

Start with the "solid half-annulus" $C_1=A_1\subset E^2$. Then inside of $A_1$ inscribe a chain $C_2$ of smaller half-annuli $A_2^i$:
$$
C_2= A_2^1\cup A_2^2 \cup ... \cup A_2^{n_2}.
$$
Repeat this by inscribing a chain $C_3$ inside of each $A_2^i$, etc. See the figure below (sorry for the poor quality).  Now, set
$$
C:= \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty C_i.
$$

[image]

The intersection $C$ will be a discontinuum which cannot be separated by any convex curve in $E^2$. The reason for the non-separation property is that every chain $C_i$  cannot be separated by a convex curve. It would be interesting to determine for what range of Hausdorff dimensions of planar discontinua this is possible. It is easy to see that if Hausdorff dimension of a compact subset $K\subset R^2$ is $<1$, then the orthogonal projection of $K$ to a straight line has Hausdorff dimension $<1$. From this it follows that every discontinuum of Hausdorff dimension $<1$ can be disconnected by a convex curve (probably even a round circle). My guess is that for all $s>1$ there exists a planar discontinuum of Hausdorff dimension 1 which cannot be separated by a convex curve. What happens in the case $s=1$, I cannot even guess.

Comment: Very interesting.  I wasn't aware of the Antoine necklace so I am also thankful for being alerted to it's existence!